# Не удалось развернуть страницу на github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

При попытке задеплоить приложение на github pages выдает вот такую ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста кто знает, как ее решить?

```bsh
 test_app@0.1.0 predeploy C:\Users\t\Desktop\test_app
> npm run build


> test_app@0.1.0 build C:\Users\t\Desktop\test_app
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  52.5 kB  build\static\js\main.cbc68637.js
  659 B    build\static\css\main.6c7a9046.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /test_app/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment


> test_app@0.1.0 deploy C:\Users\t\Desktop\test_app
> gh-pages -d build

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn git',
  path: 'git',
  spawnargs: [ 'config', 'user.name' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test_app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test_app@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\t\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-31T14_00_52_601Z-debug.log
Процесс терминала "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command npm run deploy" был завершен с кодом выхода 1.
```

Comment: А git у Вас установлен? Если установлен, виден ли он в PATH

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно уточнил @SnakeMS git не был виден в PATH. Спасибо за комментарий)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).